# How to change the label of title field

Tags: 8

How to change the label of title field bydefault its showing **Title** I need to change it to **"Custom-title"** of **node edit form** programatically.

I tried

```
 function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
if ($form_id =="slices_slices_cta_5_edit_form")
{
    kint($form[title][widget][0]['#title']);
    dpm($form[title][widget][0]['#title']->jsonSerialize());
   $form[title][widget][0]['#title']->jsonSerialize()==t("Custom-title");
     //dpm($form[title][widget][0]['#title']->getArguments());

}
```

[image]

I just want to change [string] property of class TranslatableMarkup's object of above screen shot.

How to access the value of a Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\TranslatableMarkup object within a form

**I want to do something like below example:**

```
$form[title][widget][0]['#title']->string = t('New-title');
```

Not working above solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the title label by editing the node type settings by going to Admin > Content Types > (type) > Edit. No code needed, and this can be exported to configuration.

I’m not even sure what your code is trying to do, but you don’t need it.

Comment: Actually we are using eck field module we need to change the title of Eck field programatically

Comment: Your question says the node edit form title needs to be changed. Why not just use the actual label of the fields?